# Hybrid nodes on single kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, hybrid

I am now running two kubernetes clusters.

First Cluster is running on bare metal, and Second Cluster is running on EKS.
but since maintaining EKS costs a lot, so I am finding ways to change this service as Single Cluster that autoscales on AWS.

I did tried to consider several solutions such as RHACM, Rancher and Anthos.
But those solutions are for controlling multi cluster.
I just want to change this cluster as "onpremise based cluster that autoscales (on AWS) when lack of resources"

I could find "EKS anywhere" solution but since price is too high, I want to build similar architecture.

need advice for any use cases for ingress controller, or (physical) loadbalancer, or other architecture that could satisfies those conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cluster API` is probably what you need. It is a concept of creating `Clusters` with `Machine` objects. These `Machine` objects are then provisioned using a `Provider`. This provider can be `Bare Metal Operator` provider for your bare metal nodes and `Cluster API Provider AWS` for your AWS nodes. All resting in a single cluster (see the docs below for many other provider types).

You will run a local Kubernetes cluster which will have the `Cluster API` running in it. This will include components that will allow you to be able to create different `Machine` objects and tell Kubernetes also how to provision those machines.

Here is some more reading:

1. [Cluster API Book](https://cluster-api.sigs.k8s.io/introduction.html): Excellent reading on the topic.
2. [Documentation for CAPI Provider - AWS](https://cluster-api-aws.sigs.k8s.io/).
3. [Documentation for the Bare Metal Operator](https://metal3.io/) I worked on this project for a couple of years and the community is pretty amazing. [This](https://github.com/metal3-io/cluster-api-provider-metal3) GitHub repository hosts the `CAPI Provider` for bare metal nodes.

This should definitely get you going. You can start by running different providers individually to get a taste of how they work and then work with `Cluster API` and see it in function.

Comment: Architecture will be more complex than I thought. For your answer, I knew how I should build new architecture. thanks for your help

Comment: I found out that Anthos does have functions for Cluster API. And now I should find some more solutions. I am not sure KONG api gateway have functions for Cluster API for Kubernetes

Comment: Interesting. All the best with your design!

Comment: What you typically need is a CAPI setup that has the provisioners setup correctly to provision your machine objects to the correct provider backend. There's a project called [Airship](https://www.airshipit.org/) which does precisely this. It has support for multiple provider backends as well. It might be an interesting inspiration to look at. But yes, you're right, it is a fairly complex problem, simply because the maintenance and lifecycle management becomes tricky, especially when you deploy application on such an infrastructure.